# React-native flatlist item disappearing when changing dimensions

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm developing a live streaming app in react-native for android. There is a director view that displays live streams from up to 3 cameramen.
I'm using a FlatList to display them horizontally so that the user can swipe left or right to browse through them, which works fine as is.
But the user can also zoom in on one particular stream, which changes the behavior of the view: now the selected stream takes approximately 2/3 of the view and the other sources are displayed as thumbnails on the side, like this:
[Zoomed-in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QCRG.jpg)

The issue I'm facing is that when I tinker with the dimensions, or when I try the app on other devices, sometimes one of the other sources disappears (in the above screenshot's case, it is always source 3). It only comes back when I swipe further to the right. I assumed my issue had to do with how flatlists render items but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. I'm still quite new to React-native so I bet I've missed something obvious.

Here is a snippet of my component where the FlatList is rendered:

```
return (
<FlatList
    data={data}
    horizontal={true}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
    <RenderFlatListItem
       item={item}
       index={index}
       otherProps={otherProps}
     />}
     keyExtractor={item => item.id}
 />
)
```

And an snippet of the RenderFlatListItem component:

```
return (
        <View style={ !isAnotherItemZoomedIn ? [globalStyles.container, { alignSelf: 'center', margin: 10 }] : ({ top: thumbnailPosition.yOffset, right: thumbnailPosition.xOffset })}>
                <Pressable
                    onPress={() => props.handleOnStreamPress(props.item.id, props.item.producerId)}
                    onLongPress={() => {
                        props.handleZoom(props.item);
                        props.scrollAfterZoom(props.index);
                    }}
                >
                    <DirectorZoomAnimation
                        isItemZoomedIn={isItemZoomedIn}
                        isAnotherItemZoomedIn={isAnotherItemZoomedIn}
                        item={props.item}
                        isStreamSelected={isStreamSelected} 
                    >
                        <RTCView 
                            mirror={false}
                            objectFit='cover'
                            streamURL={mediaStream.toURL()}
                            style={directorStyles.stream}
                            zOrder={0}
                        />
                    </DirectorZoomAnimation>
                    <CustomText style={[directorStyles.title, textStyles.whiteNormalBody]}>Source { videoIndex }</CustomText>
                </Pressable>
        </View>)
```

I tried a few things to fix my problem. For instance I tried wrapping my flatlist inside a View with conditional styling like: `<View style={isOneItemZoomedIn && { height: screenHeight, width: screenWidth}>{/* ... */}</View>` to check if giving dimensions to the flatlist itself would help.
I also tried to increase the flatlist's windowSize property, and to disable its scrolling with the scrollEnabled property (which works fine, but did not fix my issue).
I also considered rendering the flatlist conditionally, and when one item is being zoomed in just displaying a simple `<View>` element, but I don't know if that's a good idea.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a fix for my problem.
Using the react-native hook useWindowDimensions() helped me solved it.
Then I just gave a fixed scale to the zoomed-in and non zoomed-in elements so that they would take a bit less than 100% of the screen width.
Something along those lines:

```
const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
const zoomedInElementScale = 0.70;
const notZoomedInElementScale = 0.25;
```

Afterwards I just applied those values to the relevant items and it now works on all the devices I tried (smartphones and tablet).

Cheers